# Database mail configuration using exchange server in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, exchange-server

Can anybody please let me know if we can set up mail profile in SQL Server 2012 using an Exchange server?

I didn't find any option in server other than by using SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Database Mail supports only SMTP.  However, Exchange often configured to act as an SMTP server.  Reach out to your exchange admins to provide the host name and account information needed to setup a database mail profile.

Below is a sample configure Database Mail once you have this information.

```
-- Enable Database Mail for this instance

EXECUTE sp_configure 'show advanced', 1;

RECONFIGURE;

EXECUTE sp_configure 'Database Mail XPs',1;

RECONFIGURE;

GO



-- Create a Database Mail account

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_account_sp

    @account_name = 'Primary Account',

    @description = 'Account used by all mail profiles.',

    @email_address = 'myaddress@mydomain.com',

    @replyto_address = 'myaddress@mydomain.com',

    @display_name = 'Database Mail',

    @mailserver_name = 'mail.mydomain.com';



-- Create a Database Mail profile

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profile_sp

    @profile_name = 'Default Public Profile',

    @description = 'Default public profile for all users';



-- Add the account to the profile

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profileaccount_sp

    @profile_name = 'Default Public Profile',

    @account_name = 'Primary Account',

    @sequence_number = 1;



-- Grant access to the profile to all msdb database users

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_principalprofile_sp

    @profile_name = 'Default Public Profile',

    @principal_name = 'public',

    @is_default = 1;

GO



--send a test email

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail

    @subject = 'Test Database Mail Message',

    @recipients = 'testaddress@mydomain.com',

    @query = 'SELECT @@SERVERNAME';

GO
```